# Canot iterate through a hashmap

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I'm using the following code

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Long> entry : resultMap.entrySet()){
}
```

but I get an error: cannot convert from `Object` to `Map.Entry<Integer, Long>`
Am I forgetting to add a cast somewhere?

EDIT yes, I'd declared it as a raw type. Corrected it now, thanks.

Comment: I guess you have declared your `resultMap` as raw type `Map`. You should show the code where you declared it.

Comment: where you declared resultMap ?

Comment: What is the type of `resultMap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your `resultMap` variable is a raw type. You need:

```
Map<Integer, Long> resultMap = ...;
```

whereas I suspect you've got:

```
Map resultMap = ...;
```